# как во vue вызвать собственный метод при монтировании или в watch

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
<script>
export default {
    data: function () {
        return {
            equipments: [],
            paginatorButtons: [], 
            currentPage: 1,
            recordsInPage: 10,
            parinatorItems: 10,
            countPages: 0
        }
    },
    watch: {
        currentPage: function() {
            let app = this;
            app.loaddata();
        }
    },
    mounted() {
            var app = this;
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('currentPage', app.currentPage);
            formData.append('recordsInPage', app.recordsInPage);

            axios.get('/api/v1/equipments', formData)
                .then(function (resp) {
                    app.equipments = resp.data.equipments;
                    let countRecords = resp.data.countrecords;
                    app.countPages = Math.ceil(countRecords / app.recordsInPage);

                    for(let i = 1; i <= app.countPages; i++) {
                        app.paginatorButtons.push(i);
                    }
                })
                .catch(function (resp) {
                    alert("Не удалось загрузить данные");
                }); 
        },
    method: {
        loaddata() {
            var app = this;
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('currentPage', app.currentPage);
            formData.append('recordsInPage', app.recordsInPage);

            axios.get('/api/v1/equipments', formData)
                .then(function (resp) {
                    app.equipments = resp.data.equipments;
                    let countRecords = resp.data.countRecords;
                    app.countPages = Math.ceil(countRecords / app.recordsInPage);

                    for(i = 1; i <= app.countPages; i++) {
                        app.paginatorButtons.push(i);
                    }
                })
                .catch(function (resp) {
                    alert("Не удалось загрузить данные");
                });             
        }
    }
}
```

при попытке вызвать метод loaddata() в watch или mounted возникает ошибка loaddata is not a function. Как вызывать собственные методы? Пагинация еще не доделана

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в названии поля приложения `method`. Должно быть `methods`

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#methods

Смотрите в документацию

Comment: Точно, куда то мимо смотрел :)